# Order status — "Invoice Pending" vs. "Pending Invoice" — do they mean the same thing?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

I am working on a software platform that keeps track of work orders. A work order can have a status associated with it. There is some debate going on about how we should name these statuses. For instance, we want to create a status that indicates the work order needs to be invoiced. Some feel it should be "Pending Invoice" others say it should be "Invoice Pending". Do those two statuses have the same meaning?

Comment: Six of one, half a dozen of the others. There is a pending invoice. The invoice is pending.

Comment: To the question in the title: if an invoice is pending, you could argue that the item hasn’t been invoiced. But you can also argue that a _pending invoice_ is a metonymy for the _payment_ of the invoice, in which case the item has most certainly been invoiced. Try to avoid terms that can be interpreted as their own opposites.

Answer (score 1):

Invoice pending - means the invoice is in the pipeline, on the way to being processed

Pending invoice - means we are waiting (hanging on) for the invoice (process) to start (or to complete).

Pending, means 'hanging'.

So we are hanging on for the invoice, or the invoice is hanging on you, in these 2 examples.

Answer (score 0):

**For purposes of naming entities, it makes absolutely no difference at all.**

Neither "Invoice Pending" nor "Pending Invoice" are complete grammatically correct statements on their own. In any case, it is not necessary that the name of an entity be grammatically correct. If everyone understands what it means that is enough.

I would pick one and move on to important things.

Comment: It seems the Pending Invoice means the item, moved internally between computer processes. The Invoice Pending is the state of awaiting payment that you'd want to list as a paid/unpaid status.